# Best Practice on IF/ELSE Statement Order

Tags: .net, vb.net, if-statement

Which is a better practice?  (I'm coding in .Net if that makes a difference)

```
IF condition = true THEN
   ...true action--even if rare...
ELSE
   ...action
END IF
```

or

```
IF condition = [most common condition] THEN
   ...most common action....
ELSE
   ...least common action
END IF
```

Comment: Your question does not make much sense.  It's not clear what you are asking.  Could you please clarify?

Comment: In the second statement the else condition will never be executed

Comment: The second might be better worded "If condition = [most common condition] THEN" rather than the "true or false" - I get what you're trying to say, but that's a confusing way to phrase it.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

According to Steve McConnell, author of *Code Complete*, you should

> "Put the case you normally expect to
>   process first.  This is in line with
>   the general principle of putting code
>   that results from a decision as close
>   as possible to the decision...[*putting
>   the normal case after the if*] puts the
>   focus on reading the main flow rather
>   than on wading through the exceptional
>   cases, so the code is easier to read
>   overall."

[Code Complete](http://www.cc2e.com/), 2nd Edition, pages 356-357.

Comment: I tend to agree, but sometimes when you might have nested levels of exceptional cases it is hard to identify which is which after the normal case is done.  sometimes it's nice to see the exceptions one after another and if you've managed to drop through to the bottom you know that whatever you're processing is normal.

Comment: Ty W, that's also how you make the program do unnecessary checks most of the time.

Comment: Well that settles it. If 'code complete' writes it, then it must be so.   Reminds me a bit about these orthodox Christians: "it is written... thus it must be the truth". Difficult to have discussions about things when the gospel of a book is seen as the one and only truth.  (this will probably cost me some downvotes by the american programmers)

Comment: @reiner - is your concern with respect to referencing a book in general, or with respect to referencing Code Complete in particular?

Comment: referencing any book and that way deciding the discussion.

Answer (score 10):

Go with the most readable version for your specific case, and by the way, don't compare a boolean expression to true and false. Use `condition` and `Not condition` (`!condition` in C#.)

```
if (condition == true) // bad
if (condition) // better
```

Comment: Just curious, but why is if (condition == true) considered bad?  Too wordy?

Comment: First, it just clutters up the code. The less you write, the less you'll need to read and understand. Also, there's a possibility you miss an equals sign and it becomes  `if (condition = true)` which is not what you want. (Fortunately, the C# compiler will issue a warning, but why don't prevent it from the start?)

Comment: my personal practice is to do if(condition) for true evaluation, and if(condition == false) for false evaluation.  I find it too easy to miss if(!condition), plus I personally think it reads better "if not condition" vs. "if condition is false"

Comment: In VB, if (condition = true) is always a comparison, and never an assignment.  if (condition == true) isn't even valid.

Comment: That said, if (condition = true) is still unnecessarily redundant, and so should be avoided.

Comment: Joel: Yes, but the cluttering reason still applies.

Comment: I think 'should be avoided' is quite a harsh statement for these few extra letters. I think it's quite readable

Comment: reinier: How do you like `(((condition = True) = True) = True)`? If it shouldn't be avoided then you can inductively deduce it's OK to have infinite number of `= True` expressions :)

Comment: Should be noted that in weakly typed languages, `if (condition)` can return true if `condition` is simply a variable that exists, e.g. a string. It's not usually a big issue though.

Comment: @RanjitSingh just write if(!condition)

Comment: @EiZenHoweLL I think using if(!condition) is a bad practice as "!" sign can easily be ignored while reading the code.

Comment: @Jeff `if (expression == TRUE)` being a *bad practice* is a hold-over from **C** and the fact that a computer (ultimately) tests whether a value is equal to zero. Since **true** can (potentially) be any non-zero value it is best to use a **NOT** operator and test that it is **not non-zero** if you need to test for a **FALSE** condition. So, for example, that you don't test for a "**1**" when a particular function might return a "**2**" for its non-zero/true value. *Format your code, if necessary, so that the `!` operator is clearly visible: `if ( !something )` ...*

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you shouldn't compare to boolean values, this is, do

```
if condition then
```

instead of

```
if condition = true then
```

About your question, it depends on the natural variable names, IMO.

For example, if you are creating a client that needs to check if it's connected (the most common case)

```
if connected then
    //Proceed
else
    //Throw error
end if
```

Or, if you are creating a different program, where you have a variable, say, retrieved and you want to know if the content has been retrieved

```
if not retrieved then
   //Error
end if
```

Do not do

```
if retrieved then
else
    //Error
end if
```

Answer (score 3):

Generally, I would always put the true clause first. Something like this, for me, obfuscates meaning:

```
If not something Then
  'do something 1
Else
  'do something 2
End If
```

This results in a double-negative, much better to write it like this:

```
If something Then
  'do something 2
Else
  'do something 1
End If
```

I believe this recommendation comes from code complete. A great book well worth reading

http://www.cc2e.com/

If you're going to have more than one else then it might be better to consider a case statement.

Answer (score 3):

In the final assembly/machine code, it does make a difference.
The statement which is most likely to be executed is done in the path without the branch. This way, the pipeline isn't broken causing valuable cycles to be lost.

I have no clue if the compiler leaves your if then statement order intact and this way forces the assembly to take this optimized route.

I have read that visual studio 2008 (when it was announced) would have an optimization functionality where the compiler adds measurements at branches and then during runtime measures how often a certian path is taken. Then in subsequent recompiles the most optimal code path is preferred.

I have no clue if this feature ever made it past the 'design/academic phase'

Comment: @reinier This compile-time optimization was implemented in the HotSpot compiler for Java.  My guess is that this resulted in it also being implemented in .NET because Microsoft is under a lot of pressure to keep up with the Joneses.

Comment: The optimization i'm talking about is really about machine code level (For the C compiler). So no bytecode optimizations for .net and java like programs.

Answer (score 2):

You have received some pretty good answers already.  I'm going to approach the question from a different angle.

First, as far as performance goes it may not matter as much as you think in modern CPUs.  That's because they use a feature called branch prediction in which the CPU attempts to predict the most likely direction the code will take.  Of course, I still agree that you should place the most likely branch at the top if performance is your main concern.

Second, I prefer readability over trivial performance enhancements.  In most cases the benefit of readability outweigh those of performance.

Third, use [guard clauses](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html) when possible.  It makes the code more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Use whichever makes the code easier to read.  This is usually the second of your options.

**Edit**

In a lot of cases, it depends on what you're trying to achieve, for example, if you want to check that a connection started correctly:

```
Connect()
if connected then
    SendString("Hello!")
else
    FlagConnectionFailed()
endif
```

Whereas if you want to catch an error:

```
' Just about to send something
if not connected then
    FlagConnectionLost()
    return
endif
SendString("Still connected!")
```

But you may even want to:

```
Disconnect()
if not connected then
    return "Complete"
else
    FlagConnectionDisconnectFailure()
endif
```

(I'm not a VB programmer, so the syntax above is largely made up!)

Answer (score 1):

As others have said readability is generally more important.  However, readability means different things to different people.

For me, it typically means arranging the if statement so that the *shorter* action (in terms of lines of code) comes first, so that if the statement is near the bottom of the window I'm more likely to see the "Else" on screen.

For others, placing a "Not" in the condition can really throw them, and so they'll prefer to list it so the the If condition is always as positive as possible.

Answer (score 1):

The better practice is the second option - most common
action first.

It makes it easier to read the code as you are not
distracted by the code for the less used/exceptional case.

Answer (score 1):

If the most common case isn't the simplest to express, you might have an opportunity for re-factoring

One useful re-factoring I've found:

```
if (a.getFoo() == 1 && a.getBar() == 2)
```

can be re-factored to

```
if (a.isFooBar())
```

In come cases something nasty like this,

```
if (!(fooSet.contains(a.getValidFoo())))
```

could be

```
if (a.hasInvalidFoo(fooSet))
```

This can make option 1 also be option 2 by simplifying the evaluation of the most common condition.