# Best Practice for IF/ELSE Statement Order (when one case is never allowed)

Tags: performance, if-statement

In a simple if-else case (where the denominator of a fraction will need to be checked for a value of zero for each entry), does a correct arrangement of the statements even exist?

For example:

```
    if (!(denominator == 0))
    {
        quotient = numerator / denominator;
        System.out.println(numerator + " / " + denominator + " = " + quotient);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Division by zero is not allowed.");
    }
```

or

```
    if (denominator == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Division by zero is not allowed.");
    }
    else
    {
        quotient = numerator / denominator;
        System.out.println(numerator + " / " + denominator + " = " + quotient);
    }
```

I know this is a trivial example, but I am curious if there is any benefit to giving consideration to the ordering of the if-else statements (in a case such as above).  For less trivial testing of input/values, I can understand the consensus answer put forth here: [Best Practice on IF/ELSE Statement Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306158/best-practice-on-if-else-statement-order).

Apologies in advance if this is a bad question (or one with what should have an obvious answer).  My intent is to increase the general efficiency of my coding.  Although, I doubt that there is any significant difference between the two examples that I have given.  My newbie analysis indicates that the denominator will be tested for zero either way therefore negating any benefit of testing for the "normal case".  Please correct/enlighten me if I am wrong.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steve McConnell has some advice in Code Complete. He suggest that the non-abnormal or most frequently used branch of the if statement should appear first. (Your first code example.)

With regards to performance there should be no difference.

Comment: Thank you.  I suspected as much (first example / no performance difference).

I need to pick up a copy of Code Complete.  Seems like it has been mentioned to me one too many times lately (due to my tendency to have a lot of 'technical' questions).

Comment: Also, I asked this question because the first code example is the answer that I provided for a homework question.  But, a follow-up question seemed to be worded in such a way that it appeared that the second example was being expected.

I felt that the first case was more correct, but I am learning Java (having taught myself C# and only previously having formal training in C).

Thanks for the sanity check.

Answer (score 4):

Another answer here mentions Code Complete (a great book) as an example of having the most normal case first. I agree with this completely. However, as your behaviour isn't "if(normal) doSomething (otherwise rare case) doSomethingRarer" I don't think this applies. Insted McConnell's advice of exit early seems appropriate:

```
/* Probably should be throw new Exception(".."); */
if (denominator == 0) 
    return "Division by zero is not allowed."; 


quotient = numerator / denominator; 
return(numerator + " / " + denominator + " = " + quotient);
```

Comment: Yes, I most definitely agree with throwing here.  Or at least re-throwing.  But, we aren't that far along in this course yet.  I would *definitely* have done this if given a program and told to make it work...

So, +1 on the Code Complete?  I happen to know where a local copy is at.  Now, I must convince the wife that this is needed ;-)

Comment: Also, I am inclined to promote your answer.  Especially since you touch on "early exit" as I am sure is a best practice.  However, (to be strictly pedantic) my question was regarding ex1 or ex2.  While I agree that your ex (ex3?) is more correct, it is not an available option to me at this point.  But, I do appreciate the thorough answer.

Comment: Glad to see you're thinking about these things and definitely +1 on the code complete. I might even give it a re-read. The Pragmatic Programmer is another good, but shorter and less deep, book on program design (not that CC is particularly deep).

Answer (score 0):

In the end, it's the compiler's job to order this sort of thing for maximal performance. When it comes to a detail this trivial, your primary concern should nearly always be for simple and readable code. So the second example would get my vote because there's (marginally) less to it.

Comment: Thank you for this: "simple and readable code."

I do try... I will keep this in mind though as I work my way through this course.

You may be on to something as I have stated in the comment above that I *suspected* that example two was preferred, but I chose to submit the first example because it felt "more natural" to me.

Only having been given the next assignment did I question my original code (because I was asked to re-use the code from my first submission in a way that was not possible using the code in the first block above).